# Split a string of html into array of string, split by top level tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Say I have

```
var string = 
"<h1>Header</h1>
<p>this is a small paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>list element 1.</li>
    <li>list element 2.</li>
    <li>list element 3. With a small update.</li>
</ul>"
//newlines for clarity only
```

How can I split this string, using javascript so that I get

```
var array = string.split(/*...something here*/)

array = [
"<h1>Header</h1>",
"<p>this is a small paragraph</p>",
"<ul><li>list element 1.</li><li>list element 2.</li><li>list element 3. With a small update.</li></ul>"
]
```

I only want to split the top html elements, not the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var string = '<div><p></p></div><h1></h1>';
var elements = $(string).map(function() {
    return $('<div>').append(this).html();  // Basically `.outerHTML()`
});
```

And the result:

```
["<h1>Header</h1>", "<p>this is a small paragraph</p>", "<ul>    <li>list element 1.</li>    <li>list element 2.</li>    <li>list element 3. With a small update.</li></ul>"]
```

Comment: I know I added the jquery tag, but is there a way of doing it without jquery? and even in non-browser javascript?

Comment: @EoinMurray: Non-browser JavaScript?

Comment: like in nodejs. I vaguely remember solutions where people would attach the string to the dom and then read the children, I mean without using the dom.

Comment: @EoinMurray: You can run jQuery in Node without any problems.

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is that if the string contains an img.src then just by parsing it with jquery it makes a request.

Answer (score 2):

A performant solution ( http://jsperf.com/spliting-html ):

```
var splitter = document.createElement('div'),
  text = splitter.innerHTML = "<h1>Header</h1>\
<p>this is a small paragraph</p>\
<ul>\
    <li>list element 1.</li>\
    <li>list element 2.</li>\
    <li>list element 3. With a small update.</li>\
</ul>",
  parts = splitter.children,
  part = parts[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* do this *with regular expressions*. Your regular expression will fail if you have several nested elements of the same type, e.g.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is due to the fact that regular expressions can only process [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and HTML is a real [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) (and context-free is "more complex" than regular).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2170192

But if you don't have nested elements of the same type, you may split your html-string by taking all matches returned by the following regular expression (which uses backlinks):

```
/<(\w+).*<\/\1\s*>/igsm
```

- `<(\w+)` matches less-than-sign and several word-characters (letters, digits, underscores), while capturing the word-characters via parentheses (first capturing group).
- `.*` matches contents of the element.
- `<\/` matches opening of the end-tag.
- `\1` is the *backreference* which matches exactly the sequence of symbols captured via the first *capturing group*.
- `\s*>` matches optional whitespace and the greater-than sign.
- `igsm` are *modifiers*: case-insensitive, global, dot-matches-all-symbols and multi-line.